# Fast, reliable nosql db for indexing single docs but retrieve all at once

Tags: database, json, nosql

I need a document based database where I can update single documents but when I get them I'll get all documents at once.
In my app I have no need to search and there will be up to 100k documents.

The db should be hosted on a dedicated machine or VM and have a web api.

What is the best choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not so smart to do. If you only update one doc, why would you want to retrieve all the other 99,999 documents when you know they didn't change?

Unless you are making a computation based on that, in which case you probably want the DB to do that for you and only fetch the result?

Comment: smart or not i need to retrieve all docs at once. yes a computation would do it too of course.

Comment: Then do a computation and don't retrieve the docs, that's exactly my point. It is going to be much faster, and any DocDB would fit (Raven, Mongo, Couch).

Comment: i need the db to do the computation in this case. kind of like a hook when inserting a new doc into the db.

Comment: It's quite impossible to discuss this hypothetically without a concrete example. With RavenDB for example, you will add a new document, and an index will be updated to reflect that new data. If that index will contain the computation you wanted, all you have to do is access that index and retrieve the computation, instead of fetching all the docs. No hooks are required.